# Need to add a calculated column to a complex SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I'm fairly new to SQL Server and I'm working with a view that is created from a union of 2 select statements that are creating columns in the view and uses inner joins, left outer joins, etc). See script below.

I added the line

```
(SUM(PR.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(PR.posting_date), PR.lease_id, E.expense_id)) as Annual
```

to create a column that shows the annual sum of the individual monthly expenses. Unfortunately, because the `SUM` line is in both parts of the union I'm not getting the desired result. When the `posting_date`, `lease_id` and `expense id` are the same, then the sum in the annual column should be the same. However, the items in one half of the union have different sums than the items from the other half of the union even when all of these parameters match.

Essentially what I need to do (I think) is create the annual column after the union is complete so that the sum function sees ALL the items from both parts of the union when it does its calculation. I'm thinking about nesting the whole thing in a `SELECT` and moving the `SUM` line out of the 2 parts of the union but I don't know if this will work or if it's the right approach.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

```
create view xyz
as
SELECT     PR.amount_currency_code, CASE WHEN P.lease_payment_id IS NULL THEN PR.amount ELSE P.amount END AS amount, 
                      CASE WHEN P.lease_payment_id IS NULL THEN PR.gl_code ELSE P.gl_code END AS gl_code, 
                      CASE WHEN PR.one_time_expense_flag = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS One_Time_Flag, 
                      dbo.UDF_getRentSummaryVendor(E.expense_id, P.lease_payment_id, PR.lease_projection_id) AS vendor,
                      dbo.UDF_getRentSummaryVendorNo(E.expense_id, P.lease_payment_id, PR.lease_projection_id) as vendor_no, 
                      PS.name AS Payment_Status, PR.lease_id, PR.row_id, EC.name AS Expense_Category, P.payment_status_id, 
                      PR.lease_projection_id, E.expense_status_id, PR.posting_date,
                      PR.scheduled_payment_date AS payment_date, PR.expense_category_id,
              3 AS alloc_type,
              'Non-Standard' AS alloc_type_desc,
              'Check Details' as checkdetail,

              (SUM(PR.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(PR.posting_date), PR.lease_id, E.expense_id)) as Annual

FROM         dbo.la_tbl_lease_projection AS PR INNER JOIN   
                      dbo.la_tbl_lease AS L ON PR.lease_id = L.lease_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tlu_lease_status AS LS ON L.status_id = LS.status_id INNER JOIN                      
                      dbo.la_tlu_held_by AS HB ON L.heldby_id = HB.heldby_id INNER JOIN                                   
                      la_tbl_lease_proj_nonstd_alloc AS PA on PA.lease_projection_id = PR.lease_projection_id and PA.menu_id_key = PA.menu_id_key and PA.percentage > 0 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tbl_expense AS E ON E.expense_id = PR.expense_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tbl_lease_payment AS P ON PR.lease_projection_id = P.lease_projection_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tlu_payment_status AS PS ON P.payment_status_id = PS.payment_status_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tlu_expense_category AS EC ON PR.expense_category_id = EC.expense_category_id
WHERE     (PR.IsDeleted = 0) AND (E.IsDeleted = 0 OR
                      E.IsDeleted IS NULL)
                      and HB.system_type <> '2' and HB.IsDeleted = 0

union

SELECT     PR.amount_currency_code, CASE WHEN P.lease_payment_id IS NULL THEN PR.amount ELSE P.amount END AS amount, 
                      CASE WHEN P.lease_payment_id IS NULL THEN PR.gl_code ELSE P.gl_code END AS gl_code, 
                      CASE WHEN PR.one_time_expense_flag = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS One_Time_Flag,
                      dbo.UDF_getRentSummaryVendor(E.expense_id, P.lease_payment_id, PR.lease_projection_id) AS vendor,
                      dbo.UDF_getRentSummaryVendorNo(E.expense_id, P.lease_payment_id, PR.lease_projection_id) as vendor_no, 
                      PS.name AS Payment_Status, PR.lease_id, PR.row_id, EC.name AS Expense_Category, P.payment_status_id, 
                      PR.lease_projection_id, E.expense_status_id, PR.posting_date, 
                      PR.scheduled_payment_date AS payment_date, PR.expense_category_id,

              CASE WHEN STDALLOC.menu_id_key IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS alloc_type,
              CASE WHEN STDALLOC.menu_id_key IS NULL THEN 'None' ELSE 'Standard' END AS alloc_type_desc,    

              'Check Details' as checkdetail,
              (SUM(PR.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(PR.posting_date), PR.lease_id, E.expense_id)) as Annual
FROM         dbo.la_tbl_lease_projection AS PR INNER JOIN   
                      dbo.la_tbl_lease AS L ON PR.lease_id = L.lease_id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tlu_lease_status AS LS ON L.status_id = LS.status_id INNER JOIN                      
                      dbo.la_tlu_held_by AS HB ON L.heldby_id = HB.heldby_id LEFT OUTER JOIN 
la_tbl_area_allocation AS STDALLOC on STDALLOC.area_allocation_term_id in 
(select area_allocation_term_id from la_tbl_area_allocat_term ALLOC_TERM
where start_date = (select max(start_date) from la_tbl_area_allocat_term IN_ALLOC_TERM
    where area_term_id in (select area_term_id from la_tbl_area_term TERM where PR.posting_date between TERM.start_date 
                and TERM.end_date and PR.lease_id = TERM.lease_id and TERM.isdeleted = 0)
      and PR.posting_date between IN_ALLOC_TERM.start_date and IN_ALLOC_TERM.end_date)
AND area_allocation_term_id = (select max(area_allocation_term_id) from la_tbl_area_allocat_term IN_ALLOC_TERM
    where area_term_id in (select area_term_id from la_tbl_area_term TERM where PR.posting_date >= TERM.start_date 
                and PR.posting_date between TERM.start_date and  TERM.end_date and PR.lease_id = TERM.lease_id and TERM.isdeleted = 0)
      and PR.posting_date between IN_ALLOC_TERM.start_date and  IN_ALLOC_TERM.end_date
        and IN_ALLOC_TERM.start_date = (select max(start_date) from la_tbl_area_allocat_term INN_ALLOC_TERM
    where area_term_id in (select area_term_id from la_tbl_area_term TERM where PR.posting_date >= TERM.start_date 
                and PR.posting_date between TERM.start_date and TERM.end_date and PR.lease_id  = TERM.lease_id and TERM.isdeleted = 0)
      and PR.posting_date between INN_ALLOC_TERM.start_date and INN_ALLOC_TERM.end_date))
and PR.posting_date >= ALLOC_TERM.start_date and PR.posting_date <= ALLOC_TERM.end_date
and ALLOC_TERM.isdeleted = 0)
and STDALLOC.percentage > 0

              LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tbl_expense AS E ON E.expense_id = PR.expense_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tbl_lease_payment AS P ON PR.lease_projection_id = P.lease_projection_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tlu_payment_status AS PS ON P.payment_status_id = PS.payment_status_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.la_tlu_expense_category AS EC ON PR.expense_category_id = EC.expense_category_id
WHERE     (PR.IsDeleted = 0) AND (E.IsDeleted = 0 OR
                      E.IsDeleted IS NULL)
                      and HB.system_type <> '2' and HB.IsDeleted = 0

              and PR.lease_projection_id not in (select distinct(lease_projection_id) from la_tbl_lease_proj_nonstd_alloc where isdeleted = 0)
GO
```

Comment: Please - for this and future question : try to **limit** the problem to the **absolute minimum** to show the problem. Don't just toss a **huge pile of code** at us and expect we'll wade through all of your T-SQL here..... this is just **way too complicated** to start analyzing it, without having your database available....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by restructuring the query in the view as:

```
select t.*
from (<subquery1>
      union
      <subquery2>
     ) t
```

Then you can do:

```
select t.*,
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(posting_date), lease_id, expense_id)) as Annual
from (<subquery1>
      union
      <subquery2>
     ) t
```

You might have to be sure that all the fields -- amount, posting_date, lease_id, and expense_id -- are returned by the subqueries.

Comment: Thanks this is very close. For some reason it doesn't like the expense_id. It says Invalid column name 'expense_id'. I suppose this is because the other column names in the SUM function are prefixed with a "PR." while the expense_id is prefixed with a ".E"?

Comment: @user2414509 . . . This is because you have to include `expense_id` in both the subqueries as columns.  If you don't want it in the final view, then instead of `t.*`, list all the columns that you do want.

Comment: DONE.COM. Thanks! I figured out the expense_id include. This appears to work. Still need to check the data but seems like the right fix.